# A preimage and its image are $244◦$ apart. If the preimage was reflected over two intersecting lines, at what angle did they intersect?

Tags: geometry

A preimage and its image are $244◦$ apart. If the preimage was reflected over two intersecting lines, at what
angle did they intersect?

My book says:

> A composition of two reflections over lines that intersect at $x◦$ is
>   the same as a rotation of $2x◦$. The center of rotation is the point of
>   intersection of the two lines of reflection (Reflection over
>   Intersecting Lines Theorem).

Therefore, would I just divide 244 by 2 to get 122 degrees?

Comment: As long as you are measuring the rotation around where the lines intersect then by the definition you have given that seems correct. I don't know whether you have rules for which way the angles are measured (i.e. only counterclockwise) but another answer could be $\tfrac{360-244}{2}$.